# Different default button design behaviour

Tags: c++, qt

The problem is the following: I want to redefine (get rid of hovering effect of the button) the default Qt button style's behaviour. I only need 1 and 3 as shown on the picture under. The 2nd look comes when the button is focused.

**Hovering effect: appears when you hover the button; remains painted when you press the button and move the cursor outside the space of the button.**

[image: normal, hover, armed]

What I've tried:

1. Redefining the events:

   [How do I implement QHoverEvent in Qt?](/q/411823)

   Here I simply redefined some of the events like Move, Hover etc. and made them non-functional.

   Example Code:

   ```
   class TestButton : public QToolButton
   {
       Q_OBJECT

   public:
       TestButton (QWidget *parent = 0) :
       QToolButton(parent)
       {}

   bool event(QEvent * e)
       {
           this->clearFocus();
           this->clearMask();

           switch (e->type())
           {
           case QEvent::GraphicsSceneHoverEnter:
           case QEvent::GraphicsSceneHoverLeave:
           case QEvent::GraphicsSceneHoverMove:
           case QEvent::HoverEnter:
           case QEvent::HoverLeave:
           case QEvent::HoverMove:
               return true;
           default:
               return QWidget::event(e);
           }
       }
   };
   ```
2. Some minor hacks:

   ```
   btn->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
   ```

Comment: #2 looks like a hover state and not focus.

Comment: I tried to overwrite hoverstates to. Can I somehow disable all of them?

Comment: Post what you have tried, since for me accepting the hover events disables the hover effect.

Comment: I edited my question with source code!

Comment: Also look at the case when you push and go outside the button, the hover effect goes not away ... Only when you hover over it without push.

Comment: You may get more help, if you clarify in the question, that you want to get rid of hover effect that persists after pressing the button.

Answer (score 1):

If you accept only `HoverEnter` events then after releasing the button the hover effect will go off as soon as you move mouse away. So you need to pretend moving mouse away by sending a corresponding event.

```
bool event(QEvent * e)
{
    switch (e->type()) {
    case QEvent::HoverEnter:
        return true;
    case QEvent::MouseButtonRelease: {
        QEvent event(QEvent::Leave);
        QApplication::sendEvent(this, &event);
    }
    default:
        return QWidget::event(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actualy I needed 'case QEvent::MouseMove' and 'MouseButtonRelease 'but definitly works like a charm! So I take it as an example and accept the response.